# Creating a RGB image out of 3 healpy maps

Tags: python, rgb, healpy

I have three healpy maps (corresponding to three Stokes parameters at different frequencies) and I am trying to plot them together in the same map, to highlight differences. I want to do something like what is done in the big map in the first plot: https://sci.esa.int/web/planck/-/56323-planck-legacy-archive-foreground-component-maps . Is there a way of doing this? I have appreciated that Healpy does not have any functionality to create RGB maps from it.

Comment: Okay, let us know if you have a specific question about your code.

Comment: Please add some concrete details if you would like folk to help you. How does a map look? What are the dimensions and data types? Where are the maps? Thank you.

Comment: The specific question is that I don't even know if this is possible to create. 

A healpy map is a 1-D array floating array. Any example of healpy map would work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this in `healpy`, but you can probably do with `matplotlib`.
You can project a map using a `mollweide` projection:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/geo_demo.html

So you can get the 3 maps, normalize them appropriately (not sure if between 0  and 1 or 0 and 256), then combine them in a single 2D array where first row is R, second G and last B.

Then you can plot it with `imshow`, see that the input of `imshow` can be a `RGB` array:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html